# How to handling and notify to the user when a secondary method return a value?

Tags: c#, .net, exception

I don't know how to notify an exception to the user in this situation:

```
private void myMethod01()
{
    try
    {
        int myResult = myMethod02();
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}


private int myMethod02()
{
    try
    {
        //my code
    }
    catch
    {
        throw;
    }
}
```

One of the problems that I see with this solution is that myMethod01 in the catch, shows a message to the user. The problem is that myMethod01 perhaps can be called by another method, so if I show a message in myMethod01, perhaps the other method that call this myMethod01 shows another message to the user, so at the end, the user receive two messages. I mean, that I don't ensure that myMethod01 is the last method in the call.

Also if I show a message on myMethod02 I have to throw an exception or return a value, beause the method has to  return a value. And another problem that this could be a solution if is the main application, but if is a method from a library, then I can't show a message in this method.

I would like to know which is a good way to handle exceptions and the rethrows.

I would like to notify to the user with a message, the origin of the exception, so I want to show him if the exception occursr on myMethod02, on myMethod01 or another method that calls to myMethod01.

thank so much.

Comment: There's a serious problem with the following sentence: `I would like to notify to the user with a message, the origin of the exception, so I want to show him if the exception occursr on myMethod02, on myMethod01 or another method that calls to myMethod01.` Rest assured that the **user** does not care about any of this. The user only cares what the consequences are (Is the program going to crash? Did I just lose my data?) and what he/she can do to recover. You're confusing error **logging** (which is for programmers) with error **messaging** (which is for users).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`The problem is that myMethod01 perhaps can be called by another method, so if I show a message in myMethod01, perhaps the other method that call this myMethod01 shows another message to the user, so at the end, the user receive two messages.`

You should not show any message from business tier methods. When it comes to UI tier, Say you have a button click event handler and within that you call your method myMethod01() and which calls myMethod02() you should not show any message with myMethod01() and myMethod02(), instead of that you would bubble up the exception to caller(button click event handler). So if anything exception occurs within myMethod01() it will be caught by myMethod02() and it will rethrow it to button click handler, And you should catch the exception within the click event handler and display a meaningful message to the user, Also the exception StackTrace would have the details on origin of the exception(myMethod01()) and all the method it traveled through.

Abovementioned solution is one approach, May be you would not need to bubble up the exception but you only need to notify other methods whether the method executed successfully. for example say you have a method SaveAddress() and this method is invoked by a method SaveStudentDetails(). If you don't want to bubble up exception from SaveAddress() but you only need to notify whether SaveAddress() was successful, You would not throw the exception from the catch block of SaveAddress() and you can return a boolean from this method whether SaveAddress() was successful or not.

`another problem that this could be a solution if is the main application, but if is a method from a library, then I can't show a message in this method.`

It's never a good idea to show any user notification from a class library. Because application which make use of this class library might want to act differently when a exception is thrown from a method in your class library. Some applications might want to display different message or not to show anything. So it's the responsibility of the caller to decide what to do with an exception.

---

***Exception Logging***

Apart from handling the exception you should also have proper logging. When it comes to production environment it's sometimes impossible to figure out what went wrong when something fails without having proper logs.